# CNN with Keras - accurary incredibly low and loss negative - clearly an error on my end

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am attempting to build a CNN to classify skin-cancer related images into seven categories.
I'm relatively new to the concept of CNN and have been adapting the dog/cat classification use-case to a known skin-cancer database challenge.
The issue is that the loss and accuracy are extremely low as well as constant through the epochs.
I'm not sure where the problem is, though - my first assumption is that the number of images used is too low: 436 samples for training and 109 validation. I reduce the number of images used from 10000+ because i'm using my macbook pro.

script:

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    import sys
    import os
    import cv2

    DATA_DIR = "/Users/namefolder/PycharmProjects/skin-cancer/HAM10000_images_part_1"

    metadata = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'HAM10000_metadata.csv'))

    lesion_type_dict = {'nv': 'Melanocytic nevi',
        'mel': 'Melanoma',
        'bkl': 'Benign keratosis-like lesions ',
        'bcc': 'Basal cell carcinoma',
        'akiec': 'Actinic keratoses',
        'vasc': 'Vascular lesions',
        'df': 'Dermatofibroma'}

    metadata['cell_type'] = metadata['dx'].map(lesion_type_dict.get)
    metadata['dx_code'] = pd.Categorical(metadata['dx']).codes

    # save array of image-id and diagnosis-type (categorical)
    metadata = metadata[['image_id', 'dx', 'dx_type', 'dx_code']]

    training_data = []

    IMG_SIZE=40

    # preparing training data

    def creating_training_data(path):
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
                for index, row in metadata.iterrows():
                    if img == row['image_id']+'.jpg':
                        try:
                            training_data.append([new_array, row['dx_code']])
                        except Exception as ee:
                            pass
            except Exception as e:
                pass

        return training_data

    training_data = creating_training_data(DATA_DIR)

    import random

    random.shuffle(training_data)

    # Splitting data into X features and Y label
    X_train = []
    y_train = []
    for features, label in training_data:
        X_train.append(features)
        y_train.append(label)

    # Reshaping of the data - required by Tensorflow and Keras (*necessary step of deep-learning using these repos)
    X_train = np.array(X_train).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)

    # Normalize data - to reduce processing requirements
    X_train = X_train/255.0

    # model configuration
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), input_shape = X_train.shape[1:]))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3)))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(64))

    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.add(Activation("softmax"))

    model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error",
                 optimizer="adam",
                 metrics=["accuracy"])
```

Training model:

```
 Model fitting output:

            Train on 436 samples, validate on 109 samples
            Epoch 1/20
            436/436 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/sample - loss: 11.7890 - acc: 0.0688 - val_loss: 13.6697 - val_acc: 0.0642
            Epoch 2/20
            436/436 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/sample - loss: 11.7890 - acc: 0.0688 - val_loss: 13.6697 - val_acc: 0.0642
            Epoch 3/20
            436/436 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/sample - loss: 11.7890 - acc: 0.0688 - val_loss: 13.6697 - val_acc: 0.0642
            Epoch 4/20
            436/436 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/sample - loss: 11.7890 - acc: 0.0688 - val_loss: 13.6697 - val_acc: 0.0642
            Epoch 5/20
            436/436 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/sample - loss: 11.7890 - acc: 0.0688 - val_loss: 13.6697 - val_acc: 0.0642
            Epoch 6/20
            436/436 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/sample - loss: 11.7890 - acc: 0.0688 - val_loss: 13.6697 - val_acc: 0.0642
            Epoch 7/20
            436/436 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/sample - loss: 11.7890 - acc: 0.0688 - val_loss: 13.6697 - val_acc: 0.0642
            Epoch 8/20
            436/436 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/sample - loss: 11.7890 - acc: 0.0688 - val_loss: 13.6697 - val_acc: 0.0642
            Epoch 9/20
            436/436 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/sample - loss: 11.7890 - acc: 0.0688 - val_loss: 13.6697 - val_acc: 0.0642
            Epoch 10/20
            436/436 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/sample - loss: 11.7890 - acc: 0.0688 - val_loss: 13.6697 - val_acc: 0.0642
            Epoch 11/20
            436/436 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/sample - loss: 11.7890 - acc: 0.0688 - val_loss: 13.6697 - val_acc: 0.0642
            Epoch 12/20
            436/436 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/sample - loss: 11.7890 - acc: 0.0688 - val_loss: 13.6697 - val_acc: 0.0642
            Epoch 13/20
            436/436 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/sample - loss: 11.7890 - acc: 0.0688 - val_loss: 13.6697 - val_acc: 0.0642
            Epoch 14/20
            436/436 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/sample - loss: 11.7890 - acc: 0.0688 - val_loss: 13.6697 - val_acc: 0.0642
            Epoch 15/20
            436/436 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/sample - loss: 11.7890 - acc: 0.0688 - val_loss: 13.6697 - val_acc: 0.0642
            Epoch 16/20
            436/436 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/sample - loss: 11.7890 - acc: 0.0688 - val_loss: 13.6697 - val_acc: 0.0642
            Epoch 17/20
            436/436 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/sample - loss: 11.7890 - acc: 0.0688 - val_loss: 13.6697 - val_acc: 0.0642
            Epoch 18/20
            436/436 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/sample - loss: 11.7890 - acc: 0.0688 - val_loss: 13.6697 - val_acc: 0.0642
            Epoch 19/20
            436/436 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/sample - loss: 11.7890 - acc: 0.0688 - val_loss: 13.6697 - val_acc: 0.0642
            Epoch 20/20
            436/436 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/sample - loss: 11.7890 - acc: 0.0688 - val_loss: 13.6697 - val_acc: 0.0642
```

Model summary:

```
Model: "sequential_16"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_30 (Conv2D)           (None, 38, 38, 64)        640       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_44 (Activation)   (None, 38, 38, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_30 (MaxPooling (None, 19, 19, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_31 (Conv2D)           (None, 17, 17, 64)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_45 (Activation)   (None, 17, 17, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_31 (MaxPooling (None, 8, 8, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_14 (Flatten)         (None, 4096)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_28 (Dense)             (None, 64)                262208    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_29 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 65        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_46 (Activation)   (None, 1)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 299,841
Trainable params: 299,841
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Can someone please advise me if this could be the case or do . you see other areas I need to change/fix?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You are using

```
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))
```

i.e., a Dense layer of only one neuron with softmax? This does not work, you need at least a dimensionality of the output of 2 in order to use softmax.

How are your labels represented?

Comment: you are right. I haven't realised that. That layer should have 7 neurons as it there are seven classes. The labels are represented as numerals. `metadata['dx_code'] = pd.Categorical(metadata['dx']).codes`

Comment: Okay, then they should be also converted to one-hot encoding, in order to match with the 7 outputs.

Comment: model.add(Dense(numClasses))

Comment: Thanks qlo5 @Max and Alvaro Romero Diaz. That in fact was the issue. Runs well now!

Answer (score 1):

Hi there writing my suggestions here because I've not earned the right to comment yet.

First of all you might be completly right with your assumption that you need more data. Also you might to consider that the data might be skewed so that one class can appeare more often in the data. I don't really know how you chose your samples ...but you might want to look out for a realisitc distribution of the classes in your small sample.

As for suggestions, I'm not sure what you try to predict, but i guess you want to find out if a image is cancerous or not. If this is the case you have a binary classification problem like with cats and dogs. So you should use a "sigmoid" activation function in your output layer instead of a "softmax". Softmax is mostlybe used for multi classification.

Futhermore I don't see any deeper issues with your code. So try to change the activation function and use more samples with the right distribution if possible.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I see someone beat me to the answer...Slow typing is a curse ;)

Comment: thanks for your comments. The distribution of the dataset is very uneven between the classes - even the full database. Therefore I will have to adjust to take that into consideration later on and have equal weighted classes. Finally, at the moment this is not a binary classification problem but a multi-classification - attempting to be able to identify seven classes of images. Following this insight, I most definitely do not have enough data ingested atm. More work coming up!